# Create project in Redmine and replicate in TestLink automatically

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, redmine, testlink

There is a clean and functional way to create a project in Redmine and even be replicated in TestLink?

Or maybe a way to create a job to read the table where the Redmine creates the project and replicate to the base TestLink?

Redmine is done in Ruby and Testlink in PHP.

Both are in the same database server and use MySql .

Comment: I was able to google that https://www.redmine.org/plugins/rp-testlinklink

Comment: @Noma4i 
This plugin does not do what I need , in fact , he does not do anything , that's the truth rs

Comment: We have written a plugin for Redmine + github, I believe you can do the same for test link. If testlink provides APIs then you can implement a plugin which push data to testlink from Redmine.